# Executar programa em determinada pasta no IIS

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-core

Gostaria de saber como faço para executar um programa exe ou jar em uma determinada pasta do IIS, através do código c# .net core. 
Teria que ser uma chamada síncrona, ou seja quando o c# realiza a chamada do jar ou exe ou bat tem que esperar o processamento para depois continuar.

Comment: Você quer executar isso toda vez que o sistema iniciar ou através de algum evento específico?

Comment: Por exemplo quando clicar em um botão, ele chama o controller que chamará meu service que executará o bat ou jar passando um parâmetro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize o Process.

```
 using System.Diagnostics;
 Process.Start("teste.exe");
```

Aguarde o processo encerrar.

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
Process process = new Process();
// Configure o processo usando as propriedades do StartInfo.
process.StartInfo.FileName = "teste.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "-n";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();// espera o processo encerrar
```